# MongoDB 3.0.5 error: symbol lookup error: undefined symbol: FIPS_mode_set

Tags: mongodb, openssl

I am testing MongoDB 3.0.5 and am unable to run ./mongod or ./mongo with the following error:

```
$ ./mongod
./mongod: symbol lookup error: ./mongod: undefined symbol: FIPS_mode_set
```

I have libssl.so.0.9.8 installed, which seems to be the required dependency.

Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems libssl.so.0.9.8 didn't get along with libssl.so.1.0.0 (which is also required on my system) since libcrypto.h only works for libss.so.1.0.0 with this setup.

I ended up creating a couple of symlinks to point 0.9.8 files to 1.0.0, which works in preliminary tests (not sure if that will cause problems down the road though).  Would be good if mongo didn't specifically require 0.9.8, but instead any version equal or greater.

Answer (score 9):

For openSuSE tumbleweed there is a workaround detailed here (it might work on other versions/distributions):

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20259

```
zypper in libopenssl-devel
rpm -e --nodeps libopenssl0_9_8
cd /usr/lib64/
ln -s libssl.so libssl.so.0.9.8
ln -s libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Comment: Thank you, been looking at this issue for a couple of hours.