# Linker errors in libqt5network.so

Tags: c++, qt

Hello dear stack overflow users,

lately I tried to compile a qt5 project on my suse machine.
It seems that my linker refuses to link the libqt5network.so against openssl.
And I fail to understand why:

```
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to    `TLSv1_1_server_method'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `SSL_set_psk_client_callback'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `TLSv1_1_client_method'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `SSL_select_next_proto'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `SSL_get0_next_proto_negotiated'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `TLSv1_2_client_method'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `SSL_CTX_set_next_proto_select_cb'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `TLSv1_2_server_method'
/usr/lib64/libQt5Network.so:-1: error: undefined reference to `EC_curve_nist2nid'
```

This Method seems the culprit, which shall download some information of a book frome the worldcat book database by its public api:

```
    void Worldcat::search(QString searchTerm){
         if(book1!=NULL){
             setIsbn(searchTerm);
             QNetworkRequest request(apiUri+getIsbn()+QString("?method=getMetadata&format=json&fl=*"));
             networkManager = new QNetworkAccessManager(this);
             connect(networkManager,SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
                     this,SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
             networkManager->get(request);
         }
     }
```

qmake.pro file

http://pastebin.com/Qk83kLaQ

The Generated make file, it is huge therefore paste bin:

http://pastebin.com/KuF9Y0JS

Comment: Perhaps there's an error in your build system/Makefile/etc. So, show the command that's run. Perhaps you've added the linker flag for linking to openssl at the wrong spot, etc.

Comment: updated the question and pasted qmake and autogenerated make file to paste bin.

Comment: The project file or the makefile do not show linking SSL libraries. Can you add CONFIG += openssl-linked in the .pro (works on Linux) ?

Comment: Did you build qt on your own? Usually OpenSSL is loaded dynamically at runtime (dlopen), unless one builds Qt with `-openssl-linked`. thus it's strange you see an error at link time

Comment: It is the standard open suse tumbleweed openssl. 
CONFIG += openssl-linked does not seem to change anything.

Answer (score 0):

I will answer it myself since I found the solution when my mongodb also refused to start, maybe it is usefeull to someone the following does help:

```
zypper in libopenssl-devel
rpm -e --nodeps libopenssl0_9_8
cd /usr/lib64/
ln -s libssl.so libssl.so.0.9.8
ln -s libcrypto.so libcrypto.so.0.9.8
```

Seems that tumble weed has a mess with its openssl librarys.

Where I found the solution:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/32406299/4958693

Original source:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-20259